# what is the need to use return 1 or -1 in the end of a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

I came across many examples of python project in which in the end some of the program, use return 1 or return -1 in the end of a method or function.. i can't figure out why ?? what is the perpose of using it.. I don't even know why return is used and when it is used.. i am getting too much confused in it.. please can someone exaplain with proper explanation.. or provide me link or something from where i can learn it..
here is one example i came across:-

```
    def add_user(self, email, password, name):
        if email.strip() not in self.users:
            self.users[email.strip()] = (password.strip(), name.strip(), get_date())
            self.save()
            return 1
        else:
            print("Email exists already")
            return -1
```

Comment: It appears that function is using 1 as a success return value and -1 as an error return value. Such things should really be documented in a docstring.

Comment: There is no such requirement for Python in general. This question is founded on a false premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` in a function is a way to see the outcome of that function when you call it later in your code.

for example:

```
def func(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

def func2(value):
    if value == 1:
        print('The provided number is even')
    elif value == -1:
        print('The provided number is odd')

value = func(6)
func2(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, it seems 1 and -1 are just ways for the function to say how it has done, useful for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment precisely why the return value has to be either 1 or -1 (because I don't your code base) but whatever is calling add_user may require those values.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a return statement is used to give a value back to the caller of the function. In your code for instance: you `return 1` if the if condition checks out, and `return -1` if the condition is not satisfied. The caller of the function `add_user()` might want to perform an operation based on if the user was added or not, so returning 1 or -1 is a way the programmer can handle the next logic. Most people return 1 or -1 for debug purposes, and let that drive the next logic.

A return statement can also be used to terminate a function. so if return 1 was the first line in the function from your example. The compiler will not look at the if statement.